# unable to expand the event div to entire screen on overflow

Tags: html, css

https://stackblitz.com/edit/horizontal-tl

please refer the above link before

There is a div with class named 'timelinebar' which is straingline tracked to show on top of list of div with class named 'events' and these div's are overflown on scroll x axis , issue is that timelinebar class div even with width of 100% is not covering all the underlying elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple solution, wrap your `mainDiv` in a container (such as `mainDivContainer` for example) and set this container to `position: relative;` instead of `mainDiv`. The timelinebar will now be relative to the content and not the viewport.

Here is a [fork](https://stackblitz.com/edit/horizontal-tl-eknhgh?file=style.css) of your stackblitz

And here is an [interesting article](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3409-using-position-absolute-inside-a-scrolling-overflow-container.htm) regarding the subject.

Answer (score 0):

This is a recurring problem when designing html. You will have the same problem with 100% height BTW.

Problem occurs because the .timelinebar has position absolute but the others flow outside of it. To width 100% work all your divs need to flow in the same plane. Because for position absolute parent nodes width 100% means the 100% of the screen, but not 100% the overflow. You need to use other approach with no position:absolute.

As there is not generic solution to this issue and each solution depends on the particular design.

Other solution is to use javascript to detect actual width in pixels of an element with .offsetWidth property and then set width in pixels for the .timelinebar div width .style.width= x + "px"; but I reserve this only for extreme cases.

Comment: can you please suggest some other way to achieve without position absolute

Answer (score 0):

You can use a solution like below

```css
.mainDiv {
  width:100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  border: 1px #ddd solid;
  position: relative;
  height: 300px
}

.mainDiv > .events {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  height: 240px;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.mainDiv > .events::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 8px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0px;
  width: calc(100% + 25px );
  /* width: 100%; */
  /* overflow-y: hidden; */
  overflow: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: black;
}

.mainDiv > .events:last-child::after {
  width: calc(100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="mainDiv" class="mainDiv">
  
  <div class="events">1</div>
  <div class="events">1</div>
  <div class="events">1</div>
  <div class="events">1</div>
  <div class="events">1</div>
  <div class="events">1</div>
  <div class="events">1</div>
  <div class="events">1</div>
  <div class="events">1</div>
</div>
```

I have removed timelinebar and added a line with all property of timelinebar in `after` element of all events div
If you don't need a single div to display a middle black line you can use this solution